# How to decrypt a field sent from client to Node server using CryptoJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I am trying to adapt the following solution into my Node application to decrypt a field sent from the client browser via POST:

[How to decrypt with CryptoJS using AES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171390/how-to-decrypt-with-cryptojs-using-aes)

Seem to be going round in circles in getting values to match in the console. The values for the encryption of 'hello' match both applied from Server and from client (sending 'hello' however there is now no decryption value showing for either.

The server side code in a Node POST Route:

```
var ENC_KEY = "c2VjcmV0"; //'secret'
app.post('/hello', function (req, res) {
    console.log('POST /hello');

    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ENC_KEY);

    console.log('key: ' + key);


    console.log('client msg ("hello"): ' + req.body.msg_hello);

    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("hello", key, {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

    console.log('server msg "hello" encrypted to: ' + encrypted);

    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

    console.log('server msg decrypted: ' + hex2a(decrypted));

    var decryptedClient = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(req.body.msg_hello, key, {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });



    console.log('client msg decrypted: ' + hex2a(decryptedClient));

    res.end(JSON.stringify('{ response: "response" }'));
});
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: If you're using node, why not use the built-in crypto module? It'll perform faster and I imagine you'd find more examples for it.

Comment: dunno if these are copy/paste errors, but: `var decryptKey = ENC_KEY` line is missing a `;`. Also,  `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt` and `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` should be using the same key.. in the above code, key != ENC_KEY

Comment: @neildaemond I've now corrected. Sorry was trying somethings whilst investigating on here!

Comment: @mscdex I haven't read all of the docs *yet* for node crypto but I like the options available in CryptoJS such as being able to use different modes, padding etc. however will look into it deeper now!

Comment: The built-in crypto module also allows you to choose modes (it's part of the cipher name, e.g. `aes-128-ctr` or `aes-128-ecb`) and to turn on/off PKCS padding, etc. It also provides node stream interfaces so you can hook them into a pipeline with other streams.

Comment: @mscdex currently trying to achieve the equivalent in the built-in crypto module! Hopefully I'll have a solution to post soon